# How can I use a regular expression to match something in the form 'stuff=foo' 'stuff' = 'stuff' 'more stuff'

Tags: regex

I need a regexp to match something like this,

'text' | 'text' | ... | 'text'(~text) = 'text' | 'text' | ... | 'text'

I just want to divide it up into two sections, the part on the left of the equals sign and the part on the right. Any of the 'text' entries can have "=" between the ' characters though. I was thinking of trying to match an even number of 's followed by a =, but I'm not sure how to match an even number of something.. Also note I don't know how many entries on either side there could be. A couple examples,

'51NL9637X33' | 'ISL6262ACRZ-T' | 'QFN'(~51NL9637X33) = '51NL9637X33' | 'ISL6262ACRZ-T' | 'INTERSIL' | 'QFN7SQ-HT1_P49' | '()'

Should extract,
'51NL9637X33' | 'ISL6262ACRZ-T' | 'QFN'(~51NL9637X33)
and,
'51NL9637X33' | 'ISL6262ACRZ-T' | 'INTERSIL' | 'QFN7SQ-HT1_P49' | '()'

'227637'           | 'SMTU2032_1'       | 'SKT W/BAT'(~227637) =  '227637'           | 'SMTU2032_1'       | 'RENATA' | 'SKT28_5X16_1-HT5_4_P2'              | '()' :SPECIAL_A ='BAT_CR2032', PART_NUM_A='202649'

Should extract,
 '227637'           | 'SMTU2032_1'       | 'SKT W/BAT'(~227637)
and,
'227637'           | 'SMTU2032_1'       | 'RENATA' | 'SKT28_5X16_1-HT5_4_P2'              | '()' :SPECIAL_A ='BAT_CR2032', PART_NUM_A='202649'

Also note the little tilda bit at the end of the first section is optional, so I can't just look for that.

Comment: Your last example doesn't fit your specification: the `:SPECIAL_A` is outside a `'text'` region or the `(~text)` region.  What's your code supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I wouldn't use a regex for that at all. Assuming your language has a `split` operation, I'd first split on the `|` character to get a list of:

```
'51NL9637X33'
'ISL6262ACRZ-T'
'QFN'(~51NL9637X33) = '51NL9637X33'
'ISL6262ACRZ-T'
'INTERSIL'
'QFN7SQ-HT1_P49'
'()'
```

Then I'd split each of them on the `=` character to get the key and (optional) value:

```
'51NL9637X33'           <null>
'ISL6262ACRZ-T'         <null>
'QFN'(~51NL9637X33)     '51NL9637X33'
'ISL6262ACRZ-T'         <null>
'INTERSIL'              <null>
'QFN7SQ-HT1_P49'        <null>
'()'                    <null>
```

You haven't specified *why* you think a regex is the right tool for the job but most modern languages also have a `split` capability and regexes aren't necessarily the answer to every requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with paxdiablo in that regular expressions might not be the most suitable tool for this task, depending on the language you are working with.

The question "How do I match an even number of characters?" is interesting nonetheless, and here is how I'd do it in your case:

```
(?:'[^']*'|[^=])*(?==)
```

This expression matches the left part of your entry by looking for a `'` at its current position. If it finds one, it runs forward to the next `'` and thereby only matching an even number of quotes. If it does not find a `'` it matches anything that is not an equal sign and then assures that an equal sign follows the matched string. It works because the regex engine evaluates OR constructs from left to right.

You could get the left and right parts in two capturing groups by using

```
((?:'[^']*'|[^=])*)=(.*)
```

I recommend http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for tinkering with regular expressions. =)

Answer (score 0):

As paxdiablo said, you almost certainly don't want to use a regex here.  The `split` suggestion isn't bad; I myself would probably use a parser here—there's a lot of structure to exploit.  The idea here is that you formally specify the syntax of what you have—sort of like what you gave us, only rigorous.  So, for instance: a `field` is a sequence of non-single-quote characters surrounded by single quotes; a `fields` is any number of `field`s separated by white space, a `|`, and more white space; a `tilde` is non-right-parenthesis characters surrounded by `(~` and `)`; and an `expr` is a `fields`, optional whitespace, an optional `tilde`, a `=`, optional whitespace, and another `fields`.  How you express this depends on the language you are using.  In Haskell, for instance, using the Parsec library, you write each of those parsers as follows:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

field :: Parser String
field = between (char '\'') (char '\'') $ many (noneOf "'\n")

tilde :: Parser String
tilde = between (string "(~") (char ')') $ many (noneOf ")\n")

fields :: Parser [String]
fields = field `sepBy` (try $ spaces >> char '|' >> spaces)

expr :: Parser ([String],Maybe String,[String])
expr = do left <- fields
          spaces
          opt  <- optionMaybe tilde
          spaces >> char '=' >> spaces
          right <- fields
          (char '\n' >> return ()) <|> eof
          return (left, opt, right)
```

Understanding precisely how this code works isn't really important; the basic idea is to break down what you're parsing, express it in formal rules, and build it back up out of the smaller components.  And for something like this, it'll be much cleaner than a regex.

---

If you *really* want a regex, here you go (barely tested):

```
^\s*('[^']*'((\s*\|\s*)'[^'\n]*')*)?(\(~[^)\n]*\))?\s*=\s*('[^']*'((\s*\|\s*)'[^'\n]*')*)?\s*$
```

See why I recommend a parser?  When I first wrote this, I got at *least* two things wrong which I picked up (one per test), and there's probably something else.  And I didn't insert capturing groups where you wanted them because I wasn't sure where they'd go.  Now yes, I could have made this more readable by inserting comments, etc.  And after all, regexen have their uses!  However, the point is: this is not one of them.  Stick with something better.